# Agent for UnprocessedDocuments After New Mail Arrives

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript

I wish to modify some documents when they arrive in my mail-in application. (I need to remove the $REF field which then allows dragging and dropping in to folders, but that's not the point.)

I have my agent set to After New Mail Arrives and to select unprocessed documents. Designer Help for Unprocessed documents states...

[image]

With the agent properties as ....

[image]

But the agent selects any document in the Inbox which has been modified or edited rather than just the new arriving email. There is also a delay of up to a minute before the agent runs.

```
Sub Initialize
Dim session As New NotesSession
Dim db As NotesDatabase
Dim collection As NotesDocumentCollection
Dim doc As NotesDocument    
Set db = session.CurrentDatabase
Set collection = db.UnprocessedDocuments
Set doc = collection.GetFirstDocument()
While Not(doc Is Nothing)
    If doc.Hasitem("$REF") Then
        doc.Subject= "($Ref) " & doc.Subject(0) 'Only testing here will remove item if exists
    Else
        doc.Subject = "(No Ref) " & doc.Subject(0)
    End If

    
    Call doc.save(True,False)
'   Call session.UpdateProcessedDoc( doc ) 'This doesn't appear to make any difference.
    Set doc = collection.GetNextDocument(doc)
Wend

End Sub
```

Any help in running this type of script on only new mail and faster than at present, as users may edit the doc before the agent has run, would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: You don't WANT to remove $Ref... just change your folders to allow response documents without hierarchy...

Comment: Thanks Tode, but I have unticked Show Response Documents In a Hierarchy because they 'dissappeared' ie Mail Rule - when all documents - move to folder Inbox. These documents seemed to get lost! Hence I  why I ended up trying to solve the problem with removing the  $Ref

Comment: Don't workaround the problem by creating new ones. That item has a reason... Don't break Domino logic just because you do not understand how views work...

Comment: I haven't created a new problem I have fixed an issue, it works perfectly. Any lack of understanding is due to a lack of clear documentation.

Comment: Do what you want... just wanted to point out, that $Ref has a function and this will be lost...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to use trigger "**Before new mail arrives**" instead of "After new mail has arrived".

"Before new mail arrives" gets executed for every single new email **immediately**.

You get access to email document with

```
Dim session as New NotesSession
Dim doc as NotesDocument
Set doc = session.DocumentContext
```

You can find a good comparison of both triggers [here](https://support.hcltechsw.com/csm?id=kb_article&sysparm_article=KB0032961).

Comment: Thank you Knut, much slicker and more reliable it would seem.

Comment: I'm not so sure about this. Before new mail arrives executes before the doc is saved in the Inbox. I'm not sure if $Ref will be there yet.

Comment: It does seem to work Richard on my tests. Need to put it through its paces. I will add a comment back here for others if it doesn't work though.

Answer (score 0):

The delay is normal. The agent manager doesn't guarantee immediate execution.

What you might be seeing is a "first-time effect". I.e., the first time you run the agent, all of the messages are "new" because they are newer compared to Last-Run timestamp on the agent - which defaults to day zero in the distant past. Have you tried this multiple times in the same database to see if what is in unprocessed documents on the second run?

Comment: Hi Richard. I did run it multiple times, every time new mail arrived it modified the subject of all emails it had previously modified (not old ones) as per the test above so I ended up with (No Ref)(No Ref)(No Ref) + Subject - building up on the email subjects as the day went on, ie it acted on ones which the script had edited. I then stopped editing and just used a counter for the While Loop and it gave the correct results, ie only counted New Mail as it should work. My requirement is to edit though, so I abandonded it. Many thanks.

Comment: Were you by any chance editing the agent, or even re-saving it without changes in between runs? That clears that agent's Last-Run timestamp, which could cause it to want to reproccess everything. (Note: I haven't used this type of agent in a long time, and this sort of thing is exactly why I stopped.)

Comment: Yes, I was editing and testing, but there seemed little logic to its behaviour, maybe that explains some of it it but not all.